# Install OpenStack or use OpenShift

Tags: cloud, openshift, openstack

I need to deploy my web services and install Tomcat.

Which one is the best way?

To install OpenStack on my 32-bit machine as this project is just for test, or to use OpenShift?

But is it possible to use Tomcat with OpenShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use Tomcat with OpenShift, through the use of JBoss EWS cartridges, explained in detail [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/tomcat-overview.html).

First it's important to difference between OpenStack and OpenShift:

> **OpenStack** provides “Infrastructure-as-a-Service”, or “IaaS”. It
>   provides bootable virtual machines, networking, block storage, object
>   storage, and so forth.
>
> The **OpenShift** hosted service provides “Platform-as-a-Service” or
>   “PaaS”. It provides the necessary parts to quickly deploy and run a
>   LAMP application: the web server, application server, application
>   runtimes and libraries, database service, and so forth.

You could also install and deploy your own PaaS services, using OpenShift Origin:

> **OpenShift Origin** is the open source project of the software that enables the OpenShift hosted service. Using OpenShift Origin, you can
>   build your own PaaS.

Complete note [here](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-origin-vs-openstack/).

So, if you need to test your services with Tomcat, I would go on with OpenShift, remember that you have 3 gears with your free account and you could easily and quickly perform the deploy of your application. Getting started [online guide](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-overview.html) and free [ebook](https://www.openshift.com/promotions/ebook).

Comment: Much thank's for the clarifications, but is it possible to use ODE Apach on Tomcat of OpenShift?

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, it's possible: https://forums.openshift.com/tools-that-support-openshift and someone here also posted that was using a DIY cartridge with Tomcat and ODE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994037/apache-ode-on-openshift-calling-remote-web-service-timeout